# PulseAudio and MPD

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, mpd

## Problems when using `mpd` with `pulse`

Pulseaudio was created in order to enable using more than 1 audio source for one sink (**correct?**). If so, it should be possible to use one `sink` for `mpd` and another audio source right? That's exactly what I'm trying to do and I can't find the way.

#### Relevant Info

- I use `Awesome WM` and `pulseaudio` so I rely purely commands to change audio settings - No `gnome-settings` for example.
- I use mpd as a service and the user running it is `mpd` in group `audio`.
- I have 2 audio outputs of type `pulse` defined in my `/etc/mpd.conf` that use the following sinks:
  `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo` and `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`.
- I can switch between those 2 audio outputs with `mpc` or other client for `mpd` like `ncmpcpp`.
- This is the output of `grep -E "pulse|mpd|audio"`:
  `audio:x:29:pulse`
  `pulse:x:123:mpd`
  `pulse-access:x:124:mpd`
  **Bonus Question:** Why are there **2** groups for `pulse` and what is the difference between them?
- I use Ubuntu 16.04.

**The problem is** that if I want to hear music from my browser for example, I have to pause `mpd` and refresh the page. It's quite annoying and sometimes I have to refresh the page more than once to hear something.

#### What I know

- I can view the programs that use (or want to use audio) with `pacmd list-sink-inputs` and I never see `mpd` there.
- I know that `mpd` is running it's own pulseaudio session because I can see with `htop`/`top`/`ps aux` the following:
  `doron [..] /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog -vvvv`
  `mpd   [..] /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog -vvvv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the Solution in archlinux's great wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon/Tips_and_tricks#PulseAudio.

#### Notes

- You need to have the following line in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (Use the commented line if you find it):

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

- Don't use `localhost` as the server for `mpd` to talk with in `/etc/mpd.conf`, Use `127.0.0.1`.
- I would `sudo service mpd stop` before `pulseaudio --kill` and then `sudo service mpd start`.

Comment: Maybe you could change this to say: You need the following line in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`... `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1`. The first `load-module...` part may already be in your `default.pa`, uncomment it. Took me a few extra minutes to get this as I read "right after" as next line... Great solution! Thank you!!!